# libGL error: failed to open swrast

Tags: windows-subsystem-for-linux

I am facing a persistent issue involving library loading.
The error that i get:

```
libGL error: MESA-LOADER: failed to open swrast: /usr/lib/dri/swrast_dri.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory (search paths /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/dri:\$${ORIGIN}/dri:/usr/lib/dri, suffix _dri)
libGL error: failed to load driver: swrast
XRequest.148: BadMatch (invalid parameter attributes) 0x0
Segmentation fault
```

The swrest cant be found although i have ensured that the library directory is specified in the ld conf.
For some reason the linker still looks for swrast in usr/lib/dri although the file is in /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/.

The worst part is that i cant change the behaviour. Ive made sure that the directory of swrst is specified in the dynamic linker folder.

The problem orignates from error involving libGLU.so.1, while running a Python script that imports gmsh and dolfinx in a WSL Ubuntu environment. I solved initial problem by manual instalation of:

```
    libglu1 \
    libxcursor-dev \
    libxft2 \
    libxinerama1 \
    libfltk1.3-dev \ 
    libfreetype6-dev  \
    libgl1-mesa-dev \
    libocct-foundation-dev \
    libocct-data-exchange-dev
```

according to original post: https://fenicsproject.discourse.group/t/oserror-libglu-so-1/6021 although that error on its own is bizzare and should not have been a problem in the first place

I would appreciate any insights or suggestions to help resolve this problem.

Environment:

```
Windows Subsystem for Linux (WSL) 2 (Win 11)
Ubuntu 22.04
```